# Kohana  undefined method Model_User::where()

Tags: php, kohana

Начинаю осваивать данный фрэймворк.
Столкнулся с проблемой, при попытке авторизовать пользователя вылетает ошибка:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call
> to undefined method
> Model_User::where()
> MODPATH\orm\classes\Kohana\Auth\ORM.php
> [ 76 ] 74 // Load the user 75 $user =
> ORM::factory('User'); 76
> $user->where($user->unique_key($username),
> '=', $username)->find(); 77 }

собственно мой код авторизации

```
$auth = Auth::instance('orm');
//.....
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$auth->login($email, $pas))
```

Наследуюсь от Controller_My_Template он в свою очередь от Controller_Template
В как устранить проблему?

Comment: проверьте, есть ли у вас тот самый ``Model_User`` и по какой причине ``Kohana`` не может его найти

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, он был переопределен мной и там не было соотв метода). Исправил, но столкнулся с другой ошибкой.

Comment: @naym, в чём заключается новая ошибка? Не можете залогиниться?

Comment: Database method list_columns is not supported by Kohana_Database_PDO
нашел ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314739/kohana-3-2-orm-and-pdo Сделал, однако ошибка не пропала. Если вбить "фальшивое" имя столбца то СУБД ругается что нет такого столбца,а когда все они верно указаны, то все та же ошибка

Comment: @naym, ну так уберите эти столбцы. Kohana их подхватит из БД, и если всё будет работать - добавите, но будете точно знать, что ошибка в них

Comment: @xEdelweiss Отказался от PDO, и теперь все вроде как работает, но, как Вы и предположили, не могу залогиньться.

Comment: @naym, в пользу чего? Какой драйвер? ORM?  
Если так, то хэшируете ли вы пароль во время регистрации или авторизации?

Comment: @xEdelweiss  да, ORM, да, хэширую, хэши совпадают, однако instance()->login($this->request->post('email'), $pas) выдает false ($pas - хэш)

Comment: $pas - пароль в "чистом виде" должен быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Комменты закончились.*

При регистрации или авторизации с использованием ORM, хэшированием паролей занимается `Kohana`, так что надо просто присваивать пароль.
Это при условии, что вы расширили существующую модель пользователя, а не переопределили её.

В общем, посмотрите гайд по авторизации, сделайте в точности так, как советуют, а уже потом, если получится - вносите свои правки.

Comment: *передавать пароль

Comment: Передача при авторизации, присваивание при регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

[Официальная документация](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/auth/login)
И не изобретайте велосипед ;)

Comment: поменял на 
$login = Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('email'), $pas);
if($login)
{
...
} но все равно та же ошибка(

Comment: а модули ORM и auth в файле bootstrap подключили?

Comment: @kemerov4anin Само собой.

Comment: а Model_User кохановская или сами переопределили класс?

Answer (score 0):

Бери данныe с формы. Есть хелперы, советую почитать о них. Чтобы взять данные с формы,
Используй этот хелпер arr::get(). Для авторизации все просто, auth::instance()->login($login,$password);